# knockoutjs observable arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, knockout.js

To simplify the issue I am having I have come up with the following example.

```
var ViewModel = function() {
this.self = this;


self.test = ko.observableArray([]);
self.test2 = ko.observableArray([]);


self.test2.push('1');
self.test.push({
  'foo':self.test2()
});
console.log('the following console.log should output an object with foo : [1]');
console.log(self.test());


self.test2.push('2');
self.test.push({
  'foo2':self.test2()
});
console.log('this console.log should have two objects, the first one with foo : [1] and the second with foo2 : [1,2]')
console.log(self.test());

};
ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

Initially both arrays are empty

```
test = []
test2 = []
```

then we push '1' into test2

```
test = []
test2 = ['1']
```

then we push a new object into test equal to the current value of test2

```
test = [ { 'foo' : ['1'] } ]
test2 = ['1']
```

And then log the current value of test just to check

We then push '2' onto test2

```
test = [ { 'foo' : ['1'] } ]
test2 = ['1','2']
```

And then push a new object onto test with test2's current value

```
test = [ { 'foo' : ['1'] }, { 'foo2' : ['1','2'] }  ]
test2 = ['1','2']
```

When all is said and done, the console.log on the JS fiddle will show you that what I expected (above) is not what happens at all.

Both console.logs show the following values for test (note that 'foo' has '1','2' which it shouldn't)

```
test = [ { 'foo' : ['1','2'] }, { 'foo2' : ['1','2'] }  ]
```

Can anyone help explain this behavior or how to achieve the desired functionality as described?

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xLp3jdr7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
self.test.push({
  'foo':self.test2()
});
```

This puts the object (array) contained in `self.test2` into the new object. Objects are passed by reference in JavaScript, they are not copied, so when you modify the object later, this composite object is going to appear different.

One common way of getting a (shallow) copy of an array is to `slice` it:

```
self.test.push({
  'foo':self.test2().slice(0)
});
```

This will behave like you expect, as long as the array isn't itself composed of objects that might change.